# Keep file permission and owner when copying file with PHP

Tags: php, permissions, copy

How can I keep the file permission and the owner when I copy a file with PHP?

Code that copies file:

```
$source = CSS . 'customers' . DS . 'source.css';
$destination = CSS . 'customers' . DS . 'destination.css';

if(!@copy($source, $destination)) {
    $errors= error_get_last();
    echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
    echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
}
```

Output:

```
-rwxrwxrwx    1 myuser  admin  7145 11 Nov 20:02 source.css
-rw-r--r--    1 daemon  admin  7145 19 Nov 16:27 destination.css
```

Comment: You can not, if you run it from a web server (user daemon). Only root has permissions to change owner. If you run it as CLI, it will have your ownership. Only when run as CLI root, you will be able to change permissions!

Comment: You can try combination between fileowner and chown for ownership and fileperms -  chmod for permissions... But this depends on the current user rights to change file owner/mods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only admin/root can change owner of a file.

- Apache is run as user apache or daemon, and can not change ownership.
- CLI program run as user can not change owner
- CLI program run as root **can** change owner

What you can do is set the file permissions to be readable by group or all users.

```
exec( 'chmod 664 ' . $filename );  // Group only
exec( 'chmod 666 ' . $filename );  // All users
```

Filename is the absolute filename with path or relative to scripts path!

Comment: Thank you very much! That is a possible solution for me.